# I want to show my progress bar in this format col-sm-6 in >546px screen(sm) but its doesn't show any changes no matter what i do

Tags: html, css, grid, progress-bar, bootstrap-5

if bootstrap can't handle this can anyone suggest an other method
ya even I have use **col-xs-6**
all I want to show my progress bar in image shown in small screen size

[here that's how want to show my image in small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Twz.png)

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <h3 class="progress-title progress-bar-1">HTML</h3>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <h3 class="progress-title progress-bar-2">HTML</h3>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <h3 class="progress-title progress-bar-3">HTML</h3>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <h3 class="progress-title progress-bar-4">HTML</h3>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <h3 class="progress-title progress-bar-5">HTML</h3>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <h3 class="progress-title progress-bar-6">HTML</h3>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <h3 class="progress-title progress-bar-1">HTML</h3>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <h3 class="progress-title progress-bar-2">HTML</h3>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this @media only screen and (max-width:546px) if you want it smaller than 546px. if it doesnt work put !important on all of it.

```css
.row {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:auto auto;
  grid-gap:10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <h3 class="progress-title progress-bar-1">HTML</h3>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <h3 class="progress-title progress-bar-2">HTML</h3>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <h3 class="progress-title progress-bar-3">HTML</h3>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <h3 class="progress-title progress-bar-4">HTML</h3>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <h3 class="progress-title progress-bar-5">HTML</h3>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <h3 class="progress-title progress-bar-6">HTML</h3>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <h3 class="progress-title progress-bar-1">HTML</h3>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <h3 class="progress-title progress-bar-2">HTML</h3>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```